# How to check a member joined to channel via bot?

Tags: webhooks, telegram, php-telegram-bot

I want to send a link to a channel by a bot for join to another channel and check who is joined with this link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set your bot as administrator of this two channels then call this function:

```
getChatMember("@channelusername", "user_id")
```

which `@channel_username` is the second channel username and user_id is the user_id of the person who joined the second channel. But notice that you need `user_id` of the person who joined to the channel, usually this is done by a bot. When user comes to the bot, your bot will have his username so you have his `user_id` and you can use `getChatMember` function.